# Translation of "en cierta medida"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

What is the best translation of *en cierta medida* to English? It seems like there are several phrases in English that would work, but I'm not sure which best reflects the sense of the Spanish phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difficult to say without a context, but "***to a certain extent***" should work in most situations.

Answer (score 2):

**"up to a point"** ("hasta cierto punto") is another possible translation.